# Python Requests Works in Console, but not In App

Tags: python, http, request, python-3.4, intercom

I built a Python Script which is meant to upload data to an application called Intercom, using the python requests library. The idea is to insert a brand new field into the custom attributes with data we would need to key off for our auto-messaging.

The script is very long, but the method that is breaking is below:

```
def post_user(self, input_user, session=None):
    """
    :param user: a JSON object with all the user pieces needed to be posted to the endpoint
    :param session: a Requests session to be used. If None we'll create one
    """
    if not session:
        session = self.create_requests_session()
    else:
        session = session

    # JSON encode the user
    payload = json.dumps(input_user, sort_keys=True, indent=2, separators=(',', ': '))

    print(payload)  # DEBUG CODE

    # Post the data to endpoint
    response = session.post(self.endpoint, data=payload)

    # This will raise a status code on a bad status code
    response.raise_for_status()
```

Below is also the method for `create_requests_session()`:

```
def create_requests_session(self):
    """
    Start a requests session. Set Auth & Headers so we don't have to send it with each request
    :return: A new requests.Session object with auth & header values prepopulated.
    """

    session = requests.Session()
    session.auth = (self.app_id, self.api_key)
    session.headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'accept': 'application/json'}

    return session
```

When I run the entire script and step through the first `input_user` it comes in as a dict, looking like. (Note: The data is anonymized, but the structure remains the exact same):

```
 {'user_id': '123456', 
  'email': 'foo@bar.com', 
  'custom_attributes': {
      'test_cell' : 'Variation'}
 }
```

However, after delivering the user to `json.dumps(user)` and then sending it through a POST request, I got back a 404 error.

Here's the weird part. I sent this exact same user with the exact same JSON, except I created all of the parts using the Python Console (note, some lines are hidden to maintain user data anonymity):

```
In[82]: sesh = requests.session()
In[86]: header
Out[86]: {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'accept': 'application/json'}
In[87]: sesh.headers = header
In[89]: payload = json.dumps(update_user)
In[91]: response = sesh.post(endpoint, data=payload)
In[92]: response
Out[92]: <Response [200]>
```

At this point, I'm completely lost. I've attempted to set up a proxy to try and compare the requests byte by byte, but haven't had much luck with that. Any help or insight is greatly appreciated.

Comment: problem might be on your self.endpoint are you sure both are same

Comment: copy-pasted directly from my code: `self.endpoint = 'https://api.intercom.io/users'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you ensured that your authentication is valid?

`session.auth = (self.app_id, self.api_key)`

In particular, the app_id should be set to the one corresponding to the API Key (so the test app's app_id if you're using a test app).

If Intercom receives an app id it does not recognise it (currently) returns a 404, which is what you're seeing. This should be fixed now to return a 401.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't the case. I store those values in the environment and they are correct. Plus authentication failure would have resulted in a 401 status code.

Comment: @JamieOsler. I just validated this in debug, the session is getting passed the correct `app_id` and `api_key` to it's auth, and the headers are correct. Why this is so strange, is they're the same Basic Auth keys that I pass in the command-line; yet, it doesn't work in my script but it's perfectly functional in the Python Console.

Comment: I made sure to create a brand new `api_key` for the same app, and also made sure that the sessions auth headers were correct at runtime. Any ideas why I'm still unauthorized? I"m getting the error_code `"token_not_found"` The full response content is looks like:  `b'{"type":"error.list","request_id":"f6ff25d1-771e-49d1-8c8b-77c360bf53ed","errors":[{"code":"token_not_found","message":"Unauthorized"}]}'`

Comment: Very late followup to this, but we ended up discovering that the config file had a trailing whitespace after the app_id, which caused the auth failures. I think we passed that on in a more direct communication line, but I thought I would close this question. Cheers!